# Custom Radio Element View in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

Currently have a custom Form Element View:

`class Apply_View_Helper_JQueryUiFormRadio extends Zend_View_Helper_FormElement`

My form is as follows

```
$form->addElement('radio', 'name', array(
 'label' => 'etc...",
```

How would I instantiate this replacing the 'radio' string in the `addElement` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each class which extends Zend_Form_Element has public proterty "helper" so you can do it in that way:

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('item');
$element->helper = 'jQueryUiFormRadio';
$this->addElement($element);
```

In your case Apply_View_Helper_ must be added to zend_view helper script path.